# Problems centring the uls and a

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello stackoverflow people, I'm trying to make these two ul's and a in center but can't figure it out how, here is the html:

```
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-justified main_nav center-block">
                    <li><a href="#">sdfsfdsfsdfsdf</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">sdfsdfsdff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#service">dsdfasdfsds</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#works">fdvdfbtrgr</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a class="navbar-brand brand-between center-block" href="#">Website title</a>
                <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-justified main_nav center-block">                        
                    <li><a href="#team">sdfsdf</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#pricing">sdfsdfsdf</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#blog">sdfdsfsdf</a></li>               
                    <li><a href="#contact">aasds</a></li>                           
                    <li><a href="#contact">ffdsfsdf</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">sadsdasd</a></li>                            
                </ul>          
            </div>
```

And here is the jsfiddle full screen for more detailed problem: https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/19003/embedded/result/

As you can see both ul's and a is not in the center of the div wit id navbar, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this:

```
.center-block {
    display: inline-block;    
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

remove those "margin:auto;" in that class and remove the `float` from `.navbar-brand`and `.navbar-nav`

and finally your `#navbar`needs `text-align:center`

Comment: Look it still not in the center of page? https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/19005/embedded/result/

Comment: and text-align:center to `#navbar`. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a matter of removing floats in your li and displaying inline-block. This css should do the trick.

```
.navbar-nav {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav li {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
}
```